# Docker-compose - What's the purpose of -scale on a single host machine?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a simple python application `web` service with a `nginx` service serving as a reverse-proxy to it.

I noticed docker-compose has a `-scale` option, which I think the point is to setup a load balancer in front of it right?

But I don't understand, what would be the point of a load balancer if all replicas of the container are running on the same machine? Wouldn't one single container have less overhead and consenquently be faster?

From what I understand, docker-compose does not manage incremental updates when do you a `up` or anything like that, it will just update all replicas.

Assuming the python application is ideally asynchronous and/or already has multiples workers inside its container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That option does not set up a load balancer - it just starts multiple containers with that image, nothing more. To load balance, set up a cluster, or whatever strategy you use is up to you. You can include a load balancer as one of your services on your docker-compose, for example.

That is beneficial both for testing running multiple instances at the same time, and for parallelizing applications that are not multi-threaded as a single instance - for example, nodejs applications will mostly have CPU load on a single core; running multiple instances with a load balancer on the same machine is a good way to better use of your cores.

Even if your Python application is "ideally asynchronous", then you'll still suffer from having most of the CPU load only on one core because of the GIL (supposing you're using cpython), so there is still a benefit to scaling your containers.

Comment: How does it works when I run `docker-compose [service] exec` with multiple containers of that service? Does it run on them all?

Comment: `docker-compose help exec` has the answer: `--index=index: index of the container if there are multiple instances of a service [default: 1]`. So it will run on the first container running that service.